# Pipeline #37652 has failed for master in stage prepare index

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, git-push

I forked a directory in order to make changes on the master branch and then create a merge request. The problem is that every time I try to do a simple task I get the above error. For example I deleted a file named test.md and a folder named .ipynb_checkpoints. I did a git add, a git commit -m 'delete test file' and a git push. I received an email telling me that the pipeline has failed at the prepare index stage, but paradoxically the file and folder was deleted on the remote repository: which means I managed to do the task I wanted to do. I'm confused.

[image]

and when I click on the error I get this:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.8.0 (775dd39d)
  on os-gitlab-runner-06 14e2913e
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:01
Using Docker executor with image python ...
Pulling docker image python ...
Using docker image sha256:2a93c239d591553ed9c25ef20ed7c7a1542e8644f57d352e3a1446f0a5f0412d for python with digest python@sha256:ca8bd3c91af8b12c2d042ade99f7c8f578a9f80a0dbbd12ed261eeba96dd632f ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-14e2913e-project-2039-concurrent-0 via os-gitlab-runner-06...
Getting source from Git repository
00:03
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/nene.barry/howto-cards-internal/.git/
Checking out 8f4ff728 as master...
Removing .tmp/
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts
00:01
Downloading artifacts for clone (234746)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=234746 responseStatus=200 OK token=BZcLj-Y7
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:04
$ pip install natsort
Collecting natsort
  Downloading natsort-7.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: natsort
Successfully installed natsort-7.1.1
$ cp -r .tmp/policies .
cp: cannot stat '.tmp/policies': No such file or directory
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Somebody can help me to understand this please?

Comment: Please show the CI script. And even without script, it seems that you need to ask the owner to explain why his pipeline is broken. The cause may be that somebody has rebuild docker-image or deleted the .tmp/polices from the project and pushed to master without testing and that's why pipeline has become broken. So you need to investigate it. You can try to run the pipeline on master branch without changes, if the problem exists - ask the repo owner.